# How to capture text in a link tag

Tags: php, expression, preg-match-all

I need a , b and c

```
 <ol class="commalist" id="list">
<li><a class="username" href="http://www.siteurl/member/1/">a</a>, </li>
<li><a class="username" href="http://www.siteurl/member/4/">b</a>, </li>
<li><a class="username" href="http://www.siteurl/member/555/">c</a>, </li>
</ol>
```

i test

```
preg_match_all('/<a class="username" href="http:\/\/www.siteurl\/member\/(.*)\/>(.*?)<\/a>/s', $output, $matches);
```

but dont work.
pls help me.
tnx

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags, it clearly states that only Chuck Norris can parse html with regex

Comment: @andrew love the Chuck Norris comment hehe

Comment: But, if you need this expression:  
preg_match_all('#<a[^\>]*>([^\<]+)#i', $output, $matches)

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) about why parsing [X]HTML with Regex is a bad idea. (Plus your first `.*` is too greedy.)